# VPN Access in Manual Mode is not working in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've set VPN Access in manual and granted an access for a subnet.
But the unselected subnet(Not granted) is still accessible using VPN Connection. Is this known issue in Softlayer ?
I tried this in "control.softlayer.com"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are doing the changes after you have logged in [VPN Access](http://www.softlayer.com/VPN-Access), that's the reason why the restrictions were not taking effect.

You should logging again after you have been done the changes, in order that they can take effect.